# How to use circularly dependent classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, cross-reference

This code is not compiling.

What modification can I do to achieve the desired result?

### ClassOne.h

```
#ifndef _CLASS_ONE_
#define _CLASS_ONE_

#include <string>
#include "ClassTwo.h"

class ClassTwo;

class ClassOne
{
private:
    string message;     
    friend ClassTwo;
    ClassTwo m_ClassTwo;

public:
    ClassOne();
    void Display();
};

#endif
```

### ClassTwo.h

```
#ifndef _CLASS_TWO_
#define _CLASS_TWO_

#include <string>
#include "ClassOne.h"

class ClassOne;

class ClassTwo
{
private:
    string message;
    friend ClassOne;
    ClassOne m_ClassOne;

public:
    ClassTwo();
    void Display();
};

#endif
```

### ClassOne.cpp

```
#include "ClassOne.h"
#include "ClassTwo.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassOne :: ClassOne()
{
    std::cout<<"ClassOne()...called\n";
    this->m_ClassTwo.message = "ClassOne - Message\n";
}

void ClassOne :: Display()
{
    std::cout<<this->m_ClassTwo.message;
}
```

### ClassTwo.cpp

```
#include "ClassTwo.h"
#include "ClassOne.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassTwo :: ClassTwo()
{
    std::cout<<"ClassTwo()...called\n";
    this->m_ClassOne.message = "ClassTwo - Message\n";
}

void ClassTwo :: Display()
{
    std::cout<<this->m_ClassOne.message;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "ClassOne.h"
#include "ClassTwo.h"

int main()
{
    ClassOne one;
    one.Display();

    ClassTwo two;
    two.Display();
}
```

### Error messages

```
1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
4   error C2079: 'ClassTwo::m_ClassOne' uses undefined class 'ClassOne'
5   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8   error C2039: 'message' : is not a member of 'ClassTwo'
9   error C2039: 'message' : is not a member of 'ClassTwo'
10  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
11  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
12  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
13  error C2079: 'ClassOne::m_ClassTwo' uses undefined class 'ClassTwo'
14  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
15  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
16  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
17  error C2039: 'message' : is not a member of 'ClassOne'
18  error C2039: 'message' : is not a member of 'ClassOne'
19  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
20  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
21  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
22  error C2079: 'ClassTwo::m_ClassOne' uses undefined class 'ClassOne'
23  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'message'
24  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
25  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Classes or functions can be declared as `friend`, a particular instance of a class cannot be declared as `friend`, Once you have an object as member of your class it obeys the rules laid out by access specifiers & you cannot use `friend`to bypass those rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said, you need to forward declare at least one of ClassOne or ClassTwo.

You ClassOne.h could therefor look like:

```
#ifndef _CLASS_ONE_
#define _CLASS_ONE_

#include <string>

class ClassTwo;

class ClassOne
{
private:
    string message;
    ClassTwo* m_ClassTwo;

public:
    ClassOne();
    void Display();
};

#endif
```

As you can see, we declare ClassTwo, but do not include it. We basically only tell the compiler that yes, we do have a ClassTwo, but we don't really care what it contains right now.

Also look at your ClassTwo member, this is now a pointer. The reason is that a member would require the compiler to know the size of the object, which we currently have no clue what is. Therefor you need either a pointer or a ref.

Next, in your ClassOne.cpp, would will need to include ClassTwo.h, to get the functions and size of that class.

A few things though:
With a forward declaration you can not inherit from ClassTwo, use the methods of the forwarded class in the header file (How would the compiler know which methods exists?) Define functions or methods using the forwarded class, that is you have to pass by reference or pass a pointer.

Comment: I need to know one thing, Is it possible to achieve the same thing without using pointers? If I want to declare normal objects as private variables, will it work? If no, why?

Comment: You can obtain the same by using references, but doesn't seem to work in your case, as it would be passed in. It's also kind of ugly, as you assume you know the lifetime of an object that is passed in, so pointers/smart pointers is the way to go. The reason a member won't work, is that the compiler would need the size of the object. To know the size, the compiler need to see the class to compute the size, as this depends on the members of the class.

Comment: The reason it would need the size of the member, is that the size of the object will depend on the size of the member. But for a pointer/ref, the size used in the object will not depend on the size of what the pointer points to, as a pointer has a fixed size.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot, ever, compile that code. You have described a system where type A contains type B, and type B contains type A. Therefore, both type A and B recursively and infinitely contain themselves, which is impossible. You must fundamentally re-architect your code to eliminate this problem.

Also, your `friend` syntax is wrong.

Comment: Of course he can compile that code, with some minor tweaking. All he needs is forward declarations and change the member to a ref or pointer.

Comment: @martiert: As if that's *not* a fairly fundamental change.

Comment: @Saqib: It is most assuredly impossible to circularly contain member variables.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use forward declarations:

add

```
class ClassTwo;
```

to ClassOne.h

and

```
class ClassTwo;
```

to ClassTwo.h

2) You need to create your member variables (or at least one of them) dynamically, using operator new, or if you wish, with one of the smart-pointers, like `boost::shared_ptr` from boost library or `std::shared_ptr` from standard library if you use C++11.

Comment: @Saqib See part 2) — you need to convert your variables to pointers.

Comment: @DeadMG described that — you can't make objects to be recursively part of each other. If you use pointer, object is allocated in different place (in the heap to be precise), and you only store pointer to the object.